# Why a long running pl/sql code that shows ACTIVE in v$session doesn't show up in v$active_session_history

Tags: oracle

When I run the below pl/sql proc, I see the session in v$session with status=ACTIVE but I don't see this session in v$active_session_history

Can someone pls explain the reason.

```
PROCEDURE sleep(sleep_time_mins IN NUMBER DEFAULT 2) 
IS 
BEGIN 
  FOR l_index IN 1 .. (sleep_time_mins * 60)/10 
  LOOP 
    DBMS_LOCK.SLEEP(10); 
    INSERT INTO test_table(elapsed_time_secs) VALUES (l_index * 10); 
  END LOOP; 
END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`V$ACTIVE_SESSION_HISTORY` view displays all the events except the `'Idle'` events and view is updated each second.

In your case `SLEEP` is an idle event and `INSERT` is not but the `V$ACTIVE_SESSION_HISTORY` view is sampled every second and I don't think that `Insert` is taking much time so `INSERT` is not captured in the `V$ACTIVE_SESSION_HISTORY` view or It **may** be captured and removed while next sample is taken within a second.

Most of the time of your Block is going into `SLEEP` (Idle event). Hence, It is not showing any information in `V$ACTIVE_SESSION_HISTORY`

You will be able to list out the `'Idle'` events using the following query:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    V$EVENT_NAME
WHERE
    WAIT_CLASS = 'Idle';
```

Refer: [Oracle document on V$ACTIVE_SESSION_HISTORY](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/dynviews_1007.htm#REFRN30299) for more information.

Cheers!!